# Async-Call in Universal Windows Class Library

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, class-library

I have a **Universal Windows Class Library** where I want to call some async methods like:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(
    "ms-windows-store://review/?PFN=" + Package.Current.Id.FamilyName));
```

> 'IAsyncOperation' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
>   and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'IAsyncOperation' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive for 'System'?)

Of course I have System in my using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
```

I suspect I'm missing a reference in my project.json since the only dependency currently in there is

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.2"
```

Am I missing a dependency or is this a different issue?

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/357) you could try to rebuild the NuGet cache.

Comment: How have you added library (which one have you chosen as a new project)? Shouldn't there be references like *Universal.Windows* and *Microsoft.NETCore....*?

Comment: @Romasz I have added a new Visual C# -> Windows Universal -> Class Library (Universal Windows) in VS2017 RC, but there were no references added by default. I have added the "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.2" manually as well.

Comment: @Yarik clearing the nuget cache didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, I was missing a nuget package, namely `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`.

Seems like this is an issue with the Visual Studio 2017 RC project templates.